# Building interface to change the order of products using CodeIgniter with GroceryCRUD

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm using CodeIgniter with GroceryCRUD, this is my MySQL table with all the products where "pro_id" is the PRIMARY KEY

[image]

I'm using a model to get the top 8 products and then display 8 of them in my homepage through a foreach(), however I want the web admin through his admin interface to be able to choose which products and in what order they should display.

Is there an easy way to do this using groceryCRUD? Should I create a table for each list I want the administrator to edit? What type of interface would be the best in this case? I can't wrap my mind around how it should work.

I currently have the GroceryCRUD CRUD working that lets me add, edit, delete products.